# SDF - indexing the folding space

Tags: opengl, c++, signed-distance-field

I had been repetitively watching [this part of the video](https://youtu.be/s8nFqwOho-s?t=17m3s) just trying to understand his point:

> you can optionally use the return value as cell index ... as random
>   seed to introduce some variation ...

at [the near end of the video](https://youtu.be/s8nFqwOho-s?t=46m32s) he stress that:

> don't use for loop ... anything can be achieved by repeating space ...
>   I will make an operator to repeat an interval ... give it additional
>   values like the first and the last cell index ... start by -2 and end
>   at +2 then you get 5 objects ...

How can we achieve like what he say? Do we use `clamp()` to do that? Something like:

```
float a = clamp(pMod1(pos.x,2),start_value, end_value);
```

It is brilliant that everything he present is just like magic to me.

**Update01**

I dig deeper into `SDF` research and reading more codes from `shadertoy`, and discovered this interesting `capsule` code:

```
float sdCapsule( float3 p, float3 a, float3 b, float r ) {
    float3 pa = p - a,
    ba = b - a;
    float h = clamp( dot(pa, ba) / dot(ba , ba), 0.0, 1.0 );
    return length( pa - ba * h ) - r;
}
```

Basically, `length(x)-r` will get `sphere`, for `x` as the origin of the `sphere` and `r` is radius of the sphere. so the `sdCapsule` to some extend, is a variation of `sphere`, with the `clamp()`. That means my speculation might be correct. However, I still not sure what that `clamp()` do and how to adapt it to my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulus is the operation that is used to repeat space.

If you take N mod 5, as you increase N, you'll get [0, 5) over and over and over.

If you want to constrain it to just repeating a certain number of times, you can use clamp before modulus.  When doing this, make sure that the value you clamp at is associated with empty space though, so you don't have geometry extending off into infinity.

Here is a link you are likely interested in (:

http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm

Comment: I understand that. But that will be like you said, it goes on to infinity. What I want is just do the repetition for 4 times. For example, how to achieve that?

Comment: Yeah, one way would be to clamp before modulus. You want to make sure that where you clamp is empty space so that when what you clamp extends off to infinity, that it's empty space, like you want.

Comment: Now it make sense. I keep seeing some weird artifact at the space of after the clamp that I don't understand, that is because my clamp just touches the space with part of the object, and that object will extend to infinity. Do you mind to incorporate your comment into the answer? So that people will have a clearer picture when they read the answer.